# finding magnitudes such that they produce the max resultant vector in a certain direction?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a 2d spaceshooter game where the ship has boosters.
I want to determine how much force each booster needs to exert to move my ship with the maximum force in the direction it wants to go.

The ship may have any number of boosters but will probably be a small number like 2-10.
The rotations of the boosters are known but I can't determine their magnitudes.
The magnitudes can be from 0(min) to lets say 5(max).

I got to a point where I made this equation:

`directionToGo = ForceB1*B1Direction + ForceB2*B2Direction`

But now that I'm getting more boosters I'm just thinking, ok to find what I want I have to brute force in min/middle/max forces for each direction to find the others I don't know.

So how would I go about doing this?

[image: http://i.imgur.com/2PVlDmx.png]

Had to unanswer because I haven't figured out the answer.

Comment: this sounds like Vector calculation

Comment: Do you want to use these boosters for accurate physics or is it just for a visual effect?

Comment: Not sure if it is wiimaxx i looked at all the unity vector calcs guide an couldn't see what I needed off the top of my head

Answer (score 1):

This sounds to me like a constraint maximization problem. You want to maximize the force along a certain vector while applying exactly no force along the perpendicular vector.

If your thrusters aren't all pointing towards the center of mass, another constraint you need is that zero torque is applied. This makes sure the ship isn't rotated by an imbalance of forces. Some games ignore this for simplicity, though, and assume thrusters never apply torque.

One thing to note is that you only need to do the optimization when the orientation of thrusters changes: during gameplay you can just apply the ratio of thrusts to add that force vector. (Watch out, though, moving "diagonally" requires another solution: if you just try to apply forward + sideways, you will get > 100% power from a thruster, causing an imbalance.)

That is one way to go about it--there might be a simpler solution that I'm not aware of. If you can constrain your problem further, it's more likely that there's a simpler way.

Comment: still reading/understanding your reply just got back from vacation

Comment: It's a bit of a conceptual answer, sorry if it doesn't end up helping much. I was hoping someone would come along and show that I'm wrong, because I'd be interested in a simpler way.

Comment: Ya reading again, I didn't even think about the torque yet.  I will try solving it the constraint maximization way.
The problem is I have a ship editor, and people can place a small number of boosters any way they want.  Any rotation or position as long as its attached to a hull piece. Hence why its going to be complicated to figure this out.